# openshift wildfly redirects all myrequest to port 8443 instead of 443

Tags: ssl, configuration, openshift, wildfly-10

I have installed an ssl certificate on my app on openshift. it is running on a Wildfly 10. I wanted to redirect all http requests to Https and after googling, I have been told to add

```
<security-constraint>
    <display-name>HTTPS</display-name>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>https</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <user-data-constraint>
        <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
    </user-data-constraint>
</security-constraint>
```

to the web.xml and all steps that have been describen here https://developers.openshift.com/faq/troubleshooting.html#_how_do_i_redirect_traffic_to_https

after that, when I enter http://example.com, I get redirected to https://www.example.com:8443/ instead of https://www.example.com:443/

Please help

Comment: What version of openshift are you using? Your link is for v2. In v3 you can configure routes and not touch your app at all. You can check "WFLY-2625 Undertow 'redirect-port' parameter for HTTPS" for info about adding proper redirect port to your wildfly config if you are still on v2.

Comment: I have changed the port number form 8433 to 433 and guess what, the app wouldn't start of course. Yes I am using v2, is it hard to upgrade for v3??

Comment: Redirect-port needs change, not the listening port. Upgrading to v3 - it depends. v3 is very different in that it works with docker compatible containers. It allows really great flexibility about how you deploy your app, how many containers would you use for each component, building, testing, etc. But this has some complexity cost. You'll have to learn some base things about the platform. On the other hand v2 is a dead end now and your knowledge of v3 will be useful for you in the long term even outside OpenShift. You can check Wildfly forums for a solution if you need a quick v2 deployment.